# Access user's event invitations

Tags: facebook, events, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing an application which would allow a user to better manage their events. However, after reading Facebook's Graph API, FQL and Legacy REST API documentations I did not find a way to obtain the events to which a user has been invited but not yet responded.

Is there any possible way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this is not covered in the Facebook API docs, but doing a query on the `/me/events/not_replied` graph path does the trick.

`/me/events/{declined|maybe|attending}` also work as filters on the `/me/events` path and pretty much explain themselves. Interestingly enough those three are included in the default `/me/events` but the events from `/me/events/not_replied` are not.